# PHP DomDocument removing an element scrambles HTML

Tags: php, domdocument

I am having issues removing a node using PHP DomDocument.

I have some HTML like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<script id="fr21" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

I attempt to remove the script node like so:

```
$jquery_node = $doc->getElementById('fr21'); 

$head_node = $jquery_node->parentNode;

$head_node->removeChild($jquery_node);
```

I then try to view the HTML by echo:

```
echo $doc->saveHTML().'<br><br>';
```

The HTML then becomes this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body><p>-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"&gt;</p> 
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

What just happened? The HTML has been mangled? Am I not removing the node correctly?

The weird thing is when I calculate the xPath for the jquery node it is shown as if its attached to the body node rather than the head node?

```
/html[1]/body[1]/script[1]
```

Comment: *removed possible duplicate because its not applicable. do not cv on that*

Comment: It is not an issue with the saveHTML - its more to do with the removing that is causing problems - I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the errors, you will see that it says:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): DOCTYPE improperly terminated in Entity, line: 1

Change the DOCTYPE to read

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

and it will work as expected: [demo](http://codepad.org/n46WZPtj)

Comment: Yes, you are right. My doctype was completely screwed - I didn't even notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$script_0 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0);
$doc->removeChild($script_0);
```